# Order of objects when describing a trade

Tags: word-order, objects

I wonder if there is a rule how to say it right.
Let’s say you want trade wood for straw.
So you have wood and the other one should have straw.
So you ask:

> Tauscht jemand Holz gegen Stroh?

But if you swap *Holz* and  *Stroh* it means the same.

> Tauscht jemand Stroh gegen Holz?

So which one should be first: What I have or what I want?

Comment: Reminds me of the 25-year-old joke of an ex-GDR guy who came to a gas station and said: "Ich hätte gerne eine Zündkerze für meinen Trabbi" and the guy in the shop answered: "OK, mach' ich - Guter Tausch"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simple as that:

> Ich tausche das, was ich habe, gegen das, was ich will.

You can only *tauschen*, what you already have. What you get for it, is introduced with the preposition *gegen*.

Comment: An additional problem here is the _jemand_. You are referring to the **other** person, who would want to swap what **they** have against what **you** want.

Comment: I think switching subjects should not be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

My family plays the game [*die Siedler von Catan*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Siedler_von_Catan) a lot, wherein a large part of gameplay centres around people swapping goods. I’ve noted that we hardly ever use the word *tauschen* for the direct exchange to prevent just that ambiguity. If I have wood and I need grain (it’s not really straw in the game), we usually say:

> Will jemand Getreide *abgeben?*
>
> Will jemand Holz *haben?*

With these verbs it is always clear which direction you are talking about. We only use *tauschen* in a very generic way:

> Will jemand mit mir *tauschen?*

Note that contrary to Barth’s answer, I initially understood the sentences in the wrong way, so it is definitely better to prevent any misunderstanding on the word choice level.

Comment: I also discovered the problem in that game.

Comment: I very much agree with the last paragraph, having understood offer and request like Jan. We usually go with unambiguous verbs like *biete* and *suche* or *brauche*.

Comment: I would also say that it is completely ambiguous.